# .append() in python just gets ignored?

Tags: python, nlp, append, nltk, textblob

So am trying to extract nouns from a csv file. 
Checking each value whether its a noun or not using Textblob package. 
The nouns found are appended to an empty list x. 
Then finally when the looping is finished, I print the final list expecting all nouns but Nothing happens..(The data set is huge).
Some one help me out.

```
from nltk import FreqDist
from textblob import TextBlob
import pandas as p

x = list()


data = p.DataFrame.from_csv('hl.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
data = data.reset_index()

for column in data.columns.values:
    for value in data[column]:
        blob = TextBlob(value)
##        print(blob.noun_phrases)    #this print statement gives nouns
        x.append(blob.noun_phrases)   #so I append the results to an empty list

print(x)      #When printing the final list.. NOTHING HAPPENS no empty list nothing. Python just ignores it why ???
```

Comment: I tried that too , it didnt work

Comment: Am sorry. list() and x=[ ] are actually the same.

Comment: Does blob contains object noun_phrases ?

Comment: yeah when i use the print statement inside the loop, it gives me the nouns.

Comment: are you sure code enters the loop?

Comment: but when I append the result and access it after the loop it just hangs or gives nothing

Comment: 100% sure the code enters the loop as I have no problem getting the nouns within the loop

Comment: type(blob.noun_phrases)

Comment: @ rosh -- It was in blob object, I ran after converting to str() and appending it. It seems the compiler just crashses. is it because the is huge

Comment: Can you try it with a much smaller file to see that it's working?  Because if it is huge, it's possible that either it will just take a really long time, or your app will run out of memory.

Comment: @GregHNZ  Tried with 200 rows it runs no problem. I think the problem is that my apps runs out of memory

Answer (score 1):

blob.noun_phrases returns an object of type `WordList`. Make the following modifications to your code. See if it solves the problem.

```
# First include Wordlist
from textblob import WordList

# Then create an instance of WOrdList
x = list()
y = WordList(x)
```

and

```
# Change `x.append(blob.noun_phrases)` to
y.extend(blob.noun_phrases)
```